# How to display a form with data fetched from a relational database as dropdown in symfony 4?

Tags: php, doctrine, relational-database, symfony4

Guide me suggestions to have a drop down with data's fetched from relational database in symfony 4

Referral link:

[Relational Database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html)

Comment: I am Strucked with this. Please guide with some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Controller**

Add this line

$category = $this->getDoctrine()  ->getRepository(Category::class)  ->findAll();

**In Twig**

[Add these lines in your twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAGPH.png)